# Good Alternatives to Windows Task Manager

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, task-manager

Does anyone know of any good **free** alternatives to the standard Windows Task Manager besides the Resource Monitor? I'm looking for a **lightweight** program that displays detailed info about my CPU, RAM, Hard Drive, processes, services, and etc.

Comment: Are you looking for a lightweight task manager to keep open all the time? So you can keep an eye on the system stats?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **[AnVir Task Manager Free](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/AnVir-Task-Manager-Free.shtml)** is process and startup manager. Remove
>   spyware and optimize performance.
>   Monitor and manage processes,
>   services, internet connections, DLLs,
>   drivers. Descriptions for startup
>   programs and all Windows services.
>   Alerts on new startups.
>
> Icons in tray for CPU usage and disk
>   load. Quick access to last launched
>   programs in tray. Hide windows to
>   system tray.
>
> Automatically change process priority,
>   permanently block undesired processes.
>   Furthermore, comes with an attractive
>   user interface.

[image]

*A portable version is available [here](http://www.anvir.com/download.htm).*

**[Moo0 SystemMonitor](http://www.moo0.com/?top=http://www.moo0.com/software/SystemMonitor/%23SystemMonitor)** lets you keep your eye on system resource usages of your PC. It currently supports 36 kinds of information including CPU, Memory, Network, and detailed HDD usages. Using this software, you may discover what is limiting your system performance in each occasion.

[image]

*MooO System Monitor is freeware, a portable version is available.*

Comment: The Moo0 System monitor was just the program I was looking for, thanks for the great find. :)

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Answer (score 20):

Sysinternals [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is a good Task Manager replacement, but it's more for, well, processes/services than for system info.  It's lightweight; no install needed, just unpack.

[image]

Comment: It also has the option to 'Replace Task Manager' so that when you invoke TaskMgr, you get ProcExp instead.

Comment: Yeah! Use it! It is he best!

Comment: Process Explorer is not lightweight, it take some seconds to load especially when there is application taking up the CPU resource. I need a lightweight yet powerful task manager, unfortunately ProcessExplorer is not one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 10):

A great alternative to Process Explorer is [**Process Hacker**](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/). It's also free but this one is open-source. Same informations, some more features.

[image: process hacker]

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Samurize](http://www.samurize.com/modules/news/) . Samurize is a superlight, and highly customizable. [here are some screen shots!](http://www.samurize.com/modules/myalbum/)

[image]

Comment: It won't install on Windows 7.

Comment: Ooooooh, shiny!