# Is there a "deep" task manager available in Windows XP akin to Windows 7 and Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, process, task-manager, threads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Alternatives to Windows Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/102651/good-alternatives-to-windows-task-manager)

Is there a good task manager or utility for Windows XP that gives deep visibility into the processes and threads running on the current system?  I know that the task manager on my Windows 7 PC has a lot more information than does Windows XP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

This is what I use when I need something better than the built-in XP task manager

Comment: +1 and I'll add that I use this in XP, Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server*, etc.

Comment: This is what I always use. I checked the box that uses ImageFileExecutionOptions to make Process Explorer launch instead of the builtin Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Process Explorer is the best one

Use also Autoruns, that show processes that runs in startup