# How to find memory hogs process explorer doesn't see

Tags: memory, process, process-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Alternatives to Windows Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/102651/good-alternatives-to-windows-task-manager)

I recently noticed that the physical memory graph on process explorer didn't appear to match up with the total working set memory used by the various applications in process explorer. For instance I was running virtual box with 2 gig of memory set aside for the guest operating system, and while that 2 gig showed up in the physical memory graph, it didn't appear in the working set for VirtualBox or, in fact, anywhere in the list of process explorer processes.

What other programs allocate memory that doesnt show up in the process explorer (except in the graph, where it can't be pinned down to a specific process) and how can I find them? Do antivirus programs do that

Comment: it could be some swapping issue, the memory is reserved-ish, but not in use

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. I pointed out that some processes are able to allocate memory in a way that process explorer does not pick up. Possibly it is kernel mode allocations(?) but I don't know. I gave an example of such a program, and I asked whether anyone knew of a program that would detect such memory usage. The question pointed to as an exact duplicate is quite different.

Comment: Also, it is not swapping issues. Process Explorer measures "working memory" using only the actively sitting-in-Ram portion of the application (PE does not use terminology the same way task manager does).