# Is there a modern Process Manager supporting things like grouping (Imagine tens of chrome.exe's)?

Tags: windows, process-explorer, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Alternatives to Windows Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/102651/good-alternatives-to-windows-task-manager)

Hi,

I am tired of using Windows Task Manager. Whenever I look at it, I see tens of Chrome.exe processes there. I am hoping to find a better process manager that is tailored for modern scenarios. I'd like it to group processes with the same name, give the ability to kill the entire group and maybe more.

Is there such a process manager?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) (part of Windows Sysinternals) does a good job of process management.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: +1 for Process Explorer being exactly what i was going to say. It's a pretty specific set of requirements that OP is asking for; not something you're going to find in any general process listing tool. Processes like svchost.exe, dllhost.exe, chrome.exe, iexplore.exe, or even notepad.exe can all represent distinct applications. What he really wants is the **Applications** list of Task Manager.

Comment: 1) It does not seem to total the resources when I collapse the detected groups.  2) it does not group all of the processes for a given app (exe), for example I still see multiple csrss.exe, adb.exe, bash.exe at the root of the listing.  Is there a utility which would show a labelled by .exe stacked-bar graph of the same for each resource (RAM, CPU, Disk Access, ... )

Answer (score 2):

[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653) from Microsoft/Sysinternals will do this, but if you're aiming to reduce clutter, it may still not be ideal for you.  It should allow you to collapse all the chrome processes as they should all have a common parent.