# Can Task Manager show the total memory usage for a group of processes?

Tags: windows, memory, task-manager

Some applications like Google Chrome and TweetDeck show up as several processes in Windows Task Manager.  This means that the memory reported in each row is only part of the overall amount used by that application.  Is there some way to view the total memory usage of an application or a group of related processes?

For example, in the screenshot below the total of all of the chrome.exe instances is 708,308 K, but I had to add that up manually as I can't find a way to get that total within Task Manager.

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager]

I have tried some alternatives such as Resource Monitor, Process Explorer and Process Hacker, but none of them seem to able to give the total either.  I am using ***Windows 7*** (Professional).

Comment: This has been answered already in the following thread

https://superuser.com/questions/269059/is-there-a-modern-process-manager-supporting-things-like-grouping-imagine-tens

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/269059/is-there-a-modern-process-manager-supporting-things-like-grouping-imagine-tens only answers grouping. Process Explorer does not total the values of a group.

Answer (score 32):

Use PowerShell:

- `(Get-Process chrome | Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum).sum`
- `(Get-Process tweetd* | Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum).sum`

Comment: Thanks, that gets some of the data I need, but I would not be able to use this method to find the process group with the highest total.  I want to be able to sort them like in Task Manager.

Comment: You can also add `/ 1GB` to the end to get the total in GB instead of Bytes.

Comment: add `/ (1024 * 1024)` to get the total in MB

Answer (score 24):

[Process Hacker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/processhacker/) shows memory usage grouped per process on its Tray Icon and added the Option to the Main Window as per user request in January 2016.
Here's an example screenshot:

[image: Example Screengrab]

The Main Window Option is configured in:

Options->Advanced->Include CPU (and other) usage of children in collapsed processes

With this option enabled, when you collapse a process tree, you see metrics for its entire tree.

Comment: Brilliant ! I have been looking for this for ..well..forever..ever since Chrome decided to scuttle the about:memory and its variations and Task Manager in Windows is crap, and Process Explorer too doesn't give a group solution. I had to hunt for the option you mentioned, wonder why it isn't the default. I had been cussing FF taking 1.4G now I see Chrome with 1.95 and growing ! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Process Hacker is a great tool - essentially a big "upgrade" of Process Explorer, with new open source code base, and lets you also see disk I/O (helped spot excessive I/O to `pagefile.sys`), manipulate Windows services, and much more.  Great tip, and this should be accepted answer - PowerShell is not that easy to install for most people and Process Hacker is very flexible.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft [added this capability to Task Manager as of the Insider build 16226](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/06/21/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16226-pc/). The feature will go out to everyone with the next major update of Windows 10, scheduled for September/October 2017.

Answer (score 2):

[**Update: Doesn't work since Chromium 51.**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=588790)

Enter `about:memory` in Google Chrome and you'll be redirected to `chrome://memory-redirect/`

That page has totals for all popular running browsers:

[image]

[Google Chrome's about: Pages](http://googlesystem.blogspot.nl/2008/09/google-chromes-about-pages.html)

Comment: That is useful, thanks. But I don't want just browsers.

Comment: These pages aren't accessible anymore. Chrome 73

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered already in the following thread

[Is there a modern Process Manager supporting things like grouping (Imagine tens of chrome.exe's)?](https://superuser.com/questions/269059/is-there-a-modern-process-manager-supporting-things-like-grouping-imagine-tens)

Task manager in Windows 7 does not support grouping, but now does group processes in windows 8.

Process Explorer or Process Hacker appear to be good alternatives for what you are looking to do. As well as system explorer.

Resource Monitor can show memory usage, but for a process as a whole.
[image]

Comment: I can group processes in both Process Explorer and Process Hacker, which allows me to kill a group easily, or hide child processes to avoid clutter. But both programs will show only the memory usage of the parent process, *not the total of the group*.

Comment: Use resource monitor, memory tab

Comment: Thank you @Pretzel but Resource Monitor also does not show me the *total for a group of processes*. If it works for you I would love to see a screenshot!

Comment: @Liam Provided one. Under memory, it provides the total amount being used for that process. Ex: I currently have multiple instances/tabs of firefox open, which resource monitor shows the total memory usage for. Shows the process as a whole.

Comment: That seems to be because there is a single Firefox process. Have a look at mine with many chrome.exe and only one firefox.exe http://i.imgur.com/EV83noj.png

Comment: @Liam If I open new instances of firefox, it adds onto the same sum of memory usage. But after checking, it appears that this is strictly firefox. Unfortunately, aside from the information I have provided, I've hit a dead end :(

Comment: @Pretzel, The resource monitor doesn't group Chrome process either: http://clip2net.com/clip/m485571/3802c-clip-96kb.png