# Why does enabling Hyper-V accelerate MSYS2's process launching?

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v, msys, hypervisor

When I run this loop in [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/)'s Bash shell

```bash
function test() {
    bcdedit | grep hypervisorlaunchtype
    printf "Press ENTER to begin..." 1>&2
    read
    # warm-up
    for ((i=0; i<"$1"; i++)); do $(:); done

    # actual iterations
    local tstart="$(date "+%s%3N")"
    iterations=0
    local i
    for ((i=2; i<"$1"; i++)); do $(:); done
    local tend="$(date "+%s%3N")"  # 2 extra spawns here
    printf "%s ms/spawn" $((("$tend" - "$tstart") / "$i")) 1>&2
    read
}
test 300
```

I get around **23 ms/spawn** if [`hypervisorlaunchtype`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gmarchetti/2008/12/07/turning-hyper-v-on-and-off/) is `off`, but around **4 ms/spawn** if it is `auto`.

**Here are GIFs comparing the two** with equal iterations: [**Hyper-V *off***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Estf3.gif) vs. [**Hyper-V *auto***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVID8.gif).
(Note that the CPU time statistics are *not* staying at zero because of being broken -- they're staying at zero because they are actually too small. If you leave the program running long enough, they *will* increase.)

What causes this discrepancy?

Comment: Strange, most people report exactly the opposite effect. Enabling Hyper-V in Windows 8+ is actually making it the real operating system, while Windows is relegated to running as a virtual machine, albeit with special hardware access privileges, which may slow-down performance. I could guess that one reason for this difference might be that Hyper-V pre-allocates memory differently from Windows, but which might fit better your case. Could you please give some more details about your environment and measuring method?

Comment: @harrymc: Yeah, it's blowing my mind too. The measuring method is literally the code itself -- it's timing itself (via the `date` command), just run it. I initially noticed it because I noticed MSYS2 was suddenly launching faster with Hyper-V enabled. (!) Not sure what you by my "environment" specifically... it's Windows 8.1 x64 with the latest updates, if that's what you mean. I've reproduced this on two different laptops so I don't think it's very specific to my laptops. Do you have Windows 8.1/are you able to reproduce it?

Comment: I have Windows 10 which includes a more evolved Hyper-V. I meant the way you run software. If I understand right, you run a bash loop (better show us the script), so I guess you are really measuring launch times or system calls. Try to run Resource Monitor to see where is the difference. You could also in Task Manager show the columns of Page Faults, I/O Reads, I/O Other, Handles and Threads - the differences in execution profile might help. Even if no differences are observed, this is a useful fact.

Comment: @harrymc: This code above *is* the script -- I just copy-paste this in the shell and watch the output. I'll try to see if I can gather that info but it might be a bit before I get around to it. It would be helpful if you could try to run 
MSYS2 on your end and see if you observe the same behavior on Win10.

Comment: @harrymc: Actually, *whose* page faults and I/O etc. are you asking for? The parent process that is launching the children, or the children themselves? I'd expect it to be more relevant for the children but I'm not sure how to measure those since they obviously quit after a short period of time and I can't halt them just before the end.

Comment: Modify your script to execute in a long loop, accumulating the ms difference, so you have the time to observe the behavior. Resource Monitor will show general system behavior. I don't know MSYS2 enough to say if "date" is a child or built-in.

Comment: @harrymc: Oh, the entire point here is that `date` is a child, and so is the subshell that is calling it (hence the division by 2 you see in the calculation). That's why I'm saying I'm saying I can't measure the child behavior -- both processes repeatedly start and end quickly. I'll try to see if the parent yields anything but I honestly don't expect it to.

Comment: Resource Monitor will still be useful. The free [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) can do that - enable Options->Advanced->Include CPU (and other) usage of children in collapsed processes, then collapse the parent ([more info and screenshot](https://superuser.com/a/1153795/8672)).

Comment: @harrymc: Okay so when I leave the script running for ~10 seconds, I see a significant difference in the amount of I/O and page faults as well as time spent in either user- or kernel-mode in the parent Bash process. See [Hyper-V off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WirSR.png) vs. [Hyper-V auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZKSp.png). Not sure what to make of this though.

Comment: Are you sure the working period was about the same for both? The "Hyper-V auto" numbers are 2-4 times more than "Hyper-V off". You could maybe modify the script to stop after 10 seconds rather than rely upon your watch and take screenshots of the stats before and after executing the loop. And what is your computer?

Comment: @harrymc: Yeah I'm definitely sure, I did it multiple times. They consistently turn out like that. It seems with hyper-v the CPU is just doing more work. The computer is a ThinkPad.

Comment: Doing more work should be slower, not faster. Unlikely as it sounds, it looks like the kernel in Hyper-V is using your hardware much better than the one in Windows 8.1 (better [HAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_abstraction)?). Does your computer seem more snappy in general with Hyper-V?

Comment: @harrymc: Not really, it doesn't at all, otherwise I would've noticed it years ago. I only notice the difference in MSYS2 scripts. Could be that the kernel is using the hardware "better", but I doubt it -- the discrepancy in the cycles makes it seem more likely that there is more work to be done rather than that the same work is being done faster. My guess is there might be some artificial pause somewhere that isn't happening in the Hyper-V-enabled system, but I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: This raises the possibility that the problem is with the MSYS2 libraries. Somehow they are misunderstanding the hardware and doing some operations the slow way. Under Hyper-V the hardware identification gives better results.

Comment: @harrymc: That seems unlikely though possible. I've asked this already but you haven't said anything -- would you be willing to install MSYS2 and try to reproduce it on your machine? It doesn't pollute anything; everything is below the main \MSYS2 folder as far as I know. It seems it could be a lot easier in helping you understand what is happening than just making guesses in the dark.

Comment: @McDonald's: I've already uninstalled/reinstalled Hyper-V; haven't seen any difference. Like I said, this happens on different models of laptops --
 I don't think it's a BIOS issue (and regardless, at least one of them is up-to-date). And no, I'm not running any VM software.

Comment: @McDonald's: I've attached GIFs in the questions, check it out. Hopefully that's convincing enough that I don't need to mail over my laptop. :-)

Comment: @harrymc: I've attached GIFs in the questions and edited the script to stop after a specified number of iterations, check it out. With Hyper-V it's ridiculously faster.

Comment: You have no answers any more. I never encountered such behavior as yours and I don't need your tiny little bounty.