# Better tool for more detailed output of processes on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Alternatives to Windows Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/102651/good-alternatives-to-windows-task-manager)

I am looking for a tool that will breakdown virtual memory, caching memory, physical memory, and the lite better than what Task Manager will do. Is there something else out there besides Task Manager that people use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try Process Explorer, and go to View>System Information.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

[image]

Comment: I didn't know procexp had that much functionality. Thanks

Comment: @nobody It is really a cool tool. Thank you for marking the answer.